# Yarn removes folder within installed dependency

Tags: npm, leaflet, yarnpkg

I am using [Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) v0.19.1 to install some dependencies. I deleted my `node_modules` folder completely and did a fresh `yarn` install.

I am trying to install the dependency [leaflet](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet) using `yarn add leaflet`. The module installs successfully, except during the `Cleaning Modules...` phase, Yarn removes the `images` folder which would typically live within `leaflet/dist/images`. When I do a `npm install leaflet` this folder does not get removed.

During a yarn install, the `images` folder is present until the `Cleaning modules` phase happens.

Who/what is doing this? Is this something `yarn` does? Or is this something specified within the `leaflet` library? How could I resolve this?

I checked the `package.json` in the leaflet library and nothing seemed out of the ordinary there. It runs a jake file, but even within that file nothing is being deleted related to images.

Here is what the folder looks like, within my `node_modules` folder, for both package manager installs:

**yarn**
[image: yarn install]

**npm**
[image: npm install]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a `.yarnclean` file in my project. This added some files/folders to ignore when installing dependencies. Running `yarn clean` added this file and I wasn't aware until I saw [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2549#issuecomment-275434551). [Viewing the docs](https://yarnpkg.com/docs/cli/clean) also gave the same info.

I resolved this by removing `images` from the set of ignored directories.

Here is my `.yarnclean` file for an example:

```
# test directories
__tests__
test
tests
powered-test

# asset directories
docs
doc
website
assets

# examples
example
examples

# code coverage directories
coverage
.nyc_output

# build scripts
Makefile
Gulpfile.js
Gruntfile.js

# configs
.tern-project
.gitattributes
.editorconfig
.*ignore
.eslintrc
.jshintrc
.flowconfig
.documentup.json
.yarn-metadata.json

# misc
*.gz
*.md
```